# I have a method that accepts Datagridview name as parameter.How to build this Data grid view name Dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
private void loadDGV(DataGridView dgv)
{ 
    // populate dgv 
}
```

I have 20 datagrid views that I have to populate and the datagrids are named DGV1, DGv2, DGV3, ..., DGV20. I intended to use a for loop to build these Data grid view names

```
int NumberofDgv = 20; 

for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfDgv; i++)
{ 
    LoadDGV("DGV"+i)
}
```

How do I pass this string to the method that accepts a Datagrid view name?

I am trying to build the Data grid view name dynamically how do I convert the string "DGV"+i to the type DataGrid view name inorder to pass it as a method to LoadDGV method. I tried searching in this forum but didn't find anything relevant. Thanks in advance for you answers.

Comment: LoadDGV("DGV"+i.ToString());

Comment: @HasanMahmood I want this to be converted to a Datagridview type. Not to a string. If i used what you shared I get an error saying Cannot convert from string to DataGridview

Comment: see the Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int NumberofDgv = 20; 

for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfDgv; i++)
{ 
    DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
    dgv.Id = "DGV"+i.ToString(); 
    LoadDGV(dgv);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much..That was so simple some how couldnt think of it :)

Comment: you are welcome @Vicky, you can make my answer as Accepted if you don not have any issue.